# IOS 5.1.1 - delete documents and data with SSH

Tags: ios, ios5, ssh, jailbreak

I have a jailbroken iPod touch 4g with iOS 5.1.1. If you go to Settings --> Usage ---> APP
it shows you how much an App actually uses for itself for its Documents and Data. I would like to delete all the documents and data with SSH manually. But first I have to know where and how the Documents and Data are stored. Any Idea where the location is, what I have to delete etc.?
I would like to reset apps back to default.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps are stored in var/mobile/applications/.  The folders are just random strings, but since you just want to delete the documents of all of them, you can just go into each one and delete the data in the documents folder.

Comment: Is that all? Just delete the documents folder? Will the apps still work? (After a restart?)

Comment: actually my bad, it should be the data in the documents folder now the  actual folder, I will fix my answer.

Comment: Honestly I don't know about the library folder. Generally deleting the  data in the documents resets the app enough.